# Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 Dual Boot on Toshiba Satellite

Tags: system-installation

I recently bought a Toshiba Satellite P50, I tried installing Ubuntu 12.04.3 and 13.10 alongside Windows 8.1.

If I disable Secure Boot, but leave the UEFI mode on, I can get to the screen that asks If I want to try Ubuntu. When I select that option the screen just goes black and nothing happens.

I'm only able to load Ubuntu from a usb when the Secure Boot and the UEFI mode are both enabled. But, after I install it, the computer loads only into Windows. I ran the boot-repair after from the usb, after disabling Secure Boot, and it told me that I should disable Secure Boot, but when I did I was again unable to load it from the usb.

Thanks for taking the time to read this.
Any help or suggestions with would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Several suggestions here. Seems to be an issue with NIC but then you will only have wifi.  Toshiba Satellite P50 model number: P50-A-01E Haswell processor
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2163854

Answer (score 0):

If you did your install while secure boot was enabled, need to run boot-repair while secure-boot is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. If do that, will it set up the GRUB bootloader with secure boot? My concern with running the boot-repair on secure boot was not being able to get back into windows after.

Comment: It will likely auto-detect windows and add a boot option form the Grub2 menu (I'm not sure I never set up windows).  If not, no worries as Ubuntu's UFEI won't overwrite Windows UFEI informaton, so you'll still be able to select the UFEI Windows loader.